# Problem setting up heroku account: "WARNING: Unable to verify SSL certificate for api.heroku.com"

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app onto heroku, just to test out the process.  My app is on github (at https://github.com/toastkid/fooapp) and all my github ssh stuff is set up.  I'm following the tutorial here:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart

I'm at step 3, where i say "heroku create" and enter my heroku email and password.  I do this, and i just get this back:

```
WARNING: Unable to verify SSL certificate for api.heroku.com
To disable SSL verification, run with HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable
```

Before i try running it with that disabled ssl option i'd like to get it working normally.  Anyone know what the problem might be?

thanks, max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added `HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable` to my `.bashrc`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix this in other way. This thing started to appear in my console since I've updated  heroku gem to 2.0.5…

Comment: Ahhh it's a env variable?  Doh, i was trying to pass it to heroku.  Does that work then?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you may not have a trusty certificate installed in your machine, or maybe, you are in a corporate network with a firewall that filter packages. When the firewall open a secure package, it may attach a self-signed certificate. If this self-signed certificate is not proper installed in your machine, you can get the error.
You can verify if you get the same error with another application like **Git** or **Pypi**.

If you are in a corporate network, `HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable` is the best solution because you know that you are in a secure environment; otherwise, you should verify the trusty certificates installed in your machine.

Merely to complement:

The same solution happens to Git with the `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true`

In Pypi you can use the `--trusted-host` parameter.